Zeroth bit of right-shifted register not read correctly in PISO Verilog implementation
I have a Verilog program to implement an 8-bit PISO register:
module PISO(input clk ,input [7:0] par_in, output reg out_bit);
        reg [7:0] mem = 8'b00000000;
        reg [2:0] count = 3'b000;
        always @ (posedge clk) begin
                if (count == 3'b000) begin
                        mem <= par_in;
                        count <= 3'b111;
                end else begin
                        out_bit <= mem[0];
                        mem <= mem >> 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                end
        end
endmodule

the problem is all outputs through the output register out_bit work fine, but the MSB, read at the very end after 7 right shifts (7 clock cycles) is read as 0, no matter the value.
For example, if the input given is 10101010, the outputs are:
Bit_out:0
Bit_out:1
Bit_out:0
Bit_out:1
Bit_out:0
Bit_out:1
Bit_out:0
Bit_out:0 //Incorrectly read MSB

I have tried all manner of fixes such as changing all non blocking assignments to blocking assignments, and ensured all registers are correctly initialised, but the problem persists.
I am using iverilog version 11. How do i fix the problem with the MSB? Is it dependent on the Verilog compiler being used?


module PISO(input clk ,input [7:0] par_in, output reg out_bit);
    ...
       always @ (posedge clk) begin
               if (count == 3'b000) begin
                       mem <= par_in;
                       count <= 3'b111;
               end else begin
               ...
               end
       end
endmodule


You never assign any value to out_bit when the count is 0. So on that count, out_bit just stays the same as it was in the previous cycle.

i see....will increasing the count bit to 4 bits and counting upto 1000 before resetting to 0 solve the issue?

@Rotas Just move the out_bit assignment out of the if-else statement

@Rotas, in that case you will only get 8 bits of output every 9 cycles --- and one of the bits will just stick for two cycles. Why not just assign something appropriate to out_bit when count is 0?

@Tom Carpenter ah ok....ill try that, thank you for your help!

@The Photon ill see if i can do that, most likely ill have to reshape the logic of the program to make it better...thank you!

@Rotas, you don't if you just think carefully about the timing --- and remember you're using non-blocking assignments. That means you can shift the old value of mem[0] out to out_bit at the same time you're shifting a new value in from par_in. (You could do that with blocking assignments also, but you'd have to be careful about the order of the statements in your code)

@The Photon you mean i can assign the last value to the out_bit just before bringing the new parallel input in?

Yes. Assuming you're doing this in an FPGA that's exactly why they use 0-hold-time registers.
